# how to use lambda handler to create GET and POST methods in python?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda

I have below code for AWS lambda for GET data from DB:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):


 '''
    This function is lambda handler function.
    This function connects to DB using environment variables and
    execute SQL query.
    '''

    logging.info(f"Fetching DB connection details.")

    try:
        # Load env file
        load_dotenv()
        # Create the connection object
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            user=os.getenv('USER_NAME'),
            password=get_db_password(os.getenv('RDS_HOST')),
            host=os.getenv('RDS_HOST'),
            database=os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
            port=os.getenv('PORT'))

        # Create a cursor
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        query = "SELECT * from <table_1>; "
        result = execute_query(cursor, query)
        result_list = result["workflow_last_execution_time"].tolist()

        if not result_list:
            return {
                'statusCode': 404,
                'body': json.dumps('No date time returned from DB')
            }

        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps(result_list)
        }

    except Exception as error:
        logging.error("An unexpected error occurred: {}".format(error))
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,  # Internal Server Error
            'body': json.dumps('An error occurred: {}'.format(str(error)))
        }
    finally:
        close_connection(cursor, conn)
```

But I am not sure how do I modify the code for POST method for INSERT query? I am no-voice in AWS lambda. So, kindly suggest. I couldn't find any such article that could help me.

Comment: Do you also want to hit the same lambda via post for insert operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [example in Python in the AWS Code Examples library](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/python/cross_service/aurora_rest_lending_library) that includes GET and POST requests using API Gateway. You can clone this repository and follow the README instructions to run it yourself.

It deploys a test database:

```
py library_demo.py deploy_database
```

And a REST API

```
py library_demo.py deploy_rest
```

However, if you want to do this without API Gateway, you can now use [Lambda Endpoints directly, as described here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/announcing-aws-lambda-function-urls-built-in-https-endpoints-for-single-function-microservices/).

Using this method, you should be able to get the action something like this, and determine if it is GET or POST. You may need to check the 'Use Lambda Proxy Integration' option to get these objects.

```
context = event.get("requestContext")
request = context.get("http")
method = request.get("method")
```